# Navigating project files in intellij idea

Tags: intellij-idea, navigation, ide

I want to jump through files in the project window using the up / down buttons. Now I press the down button, then press the enter button and the focus goes to the code editor window. But I do not want the focus to go away, I want to continue jumping through the files, pressing the down button and enter when I want to open the file. I can do this using this combination: down arrow, enter, F12, down arrow, down arrow, enter, F12 ...
Is there any way to tweak this to avoid using F12?

I'm using Intellij idea 2020.3

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest reassigning shortcut combination `Main Menu | Window | Active Tool Window | Jump to Last Tool Window` to anything more suitable for you, e.g. ESC and be sure that you don't use the same shortcut for other actions and operations.